Looking for a solution to automatically wrap text in `\node`
Description: I am designing a \notemark to annotate my notes. Here is the code:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\notemark}{mm}
  {
    \tikz[baseline = (box.base)]{
      \node[inner~sep = 0pt] (box) {#1};
      \draw[purple, thin, overlay] ([yshift = -.05\baselineskip]box.south~west) -- ([yshift = -.05\baselineskip]box.south~east);
      \node[inner~sep = 0pt, overlay, yshift = -.25\baselineskip, scale = .75, text = purple, font=\ttfamily] at (box.south){#2}
    }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage[margin = 3.14cm, showframe, paperheight=10cm]{geometry}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \notemark{consectetuer adipiscing}{mark text} elit. 


Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum  \notemark{gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero}{mark text}, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. 

\end{document}

The first line works perfectly, but the second line does not behave the same.


You need to set a text width for texct wrapping to happen or warp the text in \parbox{width}{...}

I'd suggest a different approach. If you're using LuaTeX maybe you could see whether you can define something using lua-ul. The only thing you can do when using TikZ is not using a \node but instead setting a coordinate on start, write your text outside of TikZ, set another coordinate and draw what you think will be necessary inside that coordinate. There should be answers showcasing this approach on the page. Search for something like multi-line underline and TikZ.

Only setting the text width like @daleif suggested will indeed create a line break, but it'll not follow your nomal text, instead you'd get a box with two lines and the lines around that construct would stretch. That's not what you're after.
